# Why does default switch keep repeating itself?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot using discord.js using a switch. My "default:" keeps repeating itself whenever any case is run.

I've checked to see if there are any cases without breaks, I've tried to change between " and '. Does anyone know why its doing this and how to fix it?

```
const wrongResponse = ["1", "2", "3"];
var randomResponse = wrongResponse[Math.floor(Math.random() * wrongResponse.length)];

bot.on("message", message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(calling.length).split(" ");
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'commands':
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setDescription("commands here");
            message.channel.send(embed);
            break;

        case 'search':
            message.reply("nothing yet");
            break;

        default:
            message.reply(randomResponse);
            break;
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet online so we can run and see what is happening?

Comment: What does args[0] eq

Comment: args[0] should equal "&", so to call the case it will need to use &commands

Comment: Also, what are the values of `message.content` and `calling`?

Comment: @applecrab if `args[0]` is equal to `"&"` then how could it *also* equal `'commands'` or `'search'`?

Comment: calling is = &, message.content is one of the library functions. what i meant is that when you use the switch case, the args[0] will be **&**commands. i got it from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQsUnFDT7iE

Answer (score 0):

Default is repeating itself because the code in default is emitting the message event by sending a reply, which is a message. This cycles around in an infinite loop.  Your bot needs to ignore message event emitted due to it's own actions.  You can compare the the `message.author.id` to the id of the bot, however a more a simple way to do this is to just ignore all bots, which in most cases is a good idea anyway.

```js
bot.on("message", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) { return; }
    // It's a human, do something!
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sending a message to a channel emits the message event, too. Once a message is sent that does not match any of the given cases, the bot will send `randomResponse` and will also receive that message and since the random response does not match any case either, it will do the same thing over and over again.
Consider adding a check at the beginning of your event listener that checks if the message was not sent by the bot itself.

Comment: This answer is correct, I think it's a bit unclear or confusing which may be why it's getting down voted.